# Dual Boot with tablet laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a  [Haier](http://www.haier.com/pk/products/pc/Notebook/y11c.shtml) laptop with detachable touchscreen.

The Laptop has two hard drives:

- 32gb drive on the display side
- 500gb drive on the keyboard side

I want to dual boot windows/ubuntu in such a manner that ubuntu is on the detachable display side and windows can be accessed when the keyboard is attached.

The Problem is that the windows installer won't accept the 500gb drive:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. Setup does not support configuration of or installation to disks connected through a USB or IEEE 1394 port.

There [seems to be a solution to this](https://decryptingtechnology.blogspot.de/2015/09/install-windows-10-on-usb-external-hard.html) with the Windows Startup Disk.

Is there a way to do the same recipie on my (already installed) ubuntu system?

Comment: Windows will not install to USB drives. It is licensed for one system only and the internal drive of that system. If your system has the 32GB drive configured as USB there is no way to change the hardware using software.

Answer (score 0):

When dual booting, there is always the suggestion, to fist install Windows and Ubuntu afterwards. Windows will usually destroy the GRUB and generally makes things complicated.

The [site](https://decryptingtechnology.blogspot.de/2015/09/install-windows-10-on-usb-external-hard.html) gives a thorough step-by-step tutorial what to do with the windows install disk. Since it is a Windows Problem, I suggest you handle it in Windows as suggested there.

You can install Ubuntu afterwards on your 32gb drive. I think it will be the easier way. If you still have problems related to Ubuntu feel free to come back here.